# Spring-MVC : Rate Limit per logged in user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, rate-limiting

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am working on integrating rate-limit functionality. I came upon [this](https://github.com/williewheeler/kite) library which is currently working, but any limits applied to it are applicable for all users.

We want to apply rate-limit to 2 of our critical methods, and want to apply it per user. Any ideas how to do that? Thank you.

Current code with Kite library :

```
  @GuardedBy({
            "messageServiceThrottle",
            "messageServiceRateLimiter",
            "messageServiceBreaker"
    })
    @Override
    public String editNoteWithMap(Map<String, Object> noteMap) {
   // Critical code
}
```

configuration :

```
<kite:annotation-config order="0"/>
<kite:circuit-breaker id="messageServiceBreaker" exceptionThreshold="1" timeout="30000" />
<kite:concurrency-throttle id="messageServiceThrottle" limit="1" />
<kite:rate-limiting-throttle id="messageServiceRateLimiter" limit="1" />

<context:mbean-export />
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if you tried spring security? If so, you might want to try that out.

Comment: @Zeus : Which part do you mean in Spring security is useful for rate limiting?

Comment: _"We want to apply rate-limit ... per user"_ That's what the library does. Maybe you have a different definition of "per user".

Comment: You could put a method level security using spring security.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions

Comment: @Zeus : This is for concurrent session... Even if the user is logged in from 1 location, the user can send 1000 requests which are unwanted....this is what I am trying to avoid. Thank you.